# What does 'Exchangeability' mean in multiple testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons, statistical-power, exchangeability

In [A practical guide to methods controlling false discoveries in computational biology](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-019-1716-1), the author mentioned 'Exchangeability':

[image]

According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables#:%7E:text=The%20property%20of%20exchangeability%20is,underlying%20distributional%20form%2C%20is%20exchangeable.), the definition of 'Exchangeability' is :

`In statistics, an exchangeable sequence of random variables (also sometimes interchangeable)[1] is a sequence X1, X2, X3, ... (which may be finitely or infinitely long) whose joint probability distribution does not change when the positions in the sequence in which finitely many of them appear are altered.`

If I applied the definition to the paper, does it mean that the order of distribution of p-values does not matter? What does it mean? I find it very confusing. Since the corresponding p-value of each hypothesis testing should be order-relevant since they are testing different variables? Also, what does it mean by 'The power to detect discoveries is equally likely among all tests.'?Is it possible to have hypothesis testing that has unequal powers among tests even if they have same null hypothesis (i.e. H0: The coefficient is zero for every testings.)
(I know that dependent structure of hypothesis testings may cause unequal power but I still can't understand it. Would you mind to provide some example, e.g. Simulation?)

Could you kindly provide a list of references? I'm currently seeking to expand my understanding of the topic of multiple testing. Your assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you!